# Which is a better practice in Drupal 8 to get field value from an entity?

Tags: 8

I have a product variation entity from which I need to retrieve SKU value.

I am able to get the value from the below lines, but I want to know which is a better practice and why.

1. `$entity->getSKU();`
2. `$entity->sku->value;`

Comment: Option 1 will always be (slightly) better practice, because if doesn't force the use of a magic method.

Comment: @Clive, it's definitely better practice, because if an object provides a specific getter method for the value it might be changed or overridden in future with additional logic.

Comment: Yep, couldn't agree more @4k4. There are contexts where it's better to use option 2 though. For example if you're looping over an array of string field names, you would want to use the magic methods